# htaccess / and character Redirect Issue

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess page. I want to redirect to 404.php page when / or a character is placed at the end of the url I sent to the detail page. How can I do it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)$ detay.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/_.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]


#404 hata sayfası yönlendirme kodu
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST On
</IfModule>
```

I searched for this topic on google, I opened a topic in other forums, but I did not get a successful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/_.]{1}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)$ detay.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/_.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST On
</IfModule>
```

after adding this into htaccess any url ending with a slash or a single character will redirect it to the 404.php page

I don't know how its work but its a part of some legacy code which I thought will be helpful for you as its working the same as your mentioned requirements

**After Comment**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/_.]{1}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)$ detay.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/_.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST On
</IfModule>
```

Test this

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for your help, but your code is working incorrectly. When I try to log in as localhost/blog, it does not go and when I try to go to other internal pages, I get an error.

Comment: Hey . I have added another try this one

Comment: Hello sir. I tried again but it didn't work. https://prnt.sc/kpKMUsppVdB_
Site construction is available at this link. Even when I try to go under localhost/blog/ with your code it throws at 404 page.

Comment: so you have to apply this in specific sub directory or on the main root directory.?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said

Comment: you want to apply this in overall project or on some specific pages and subpages.?

Comment: actually i will adapt it to a page first and then apply the same process throughout the whole project. If there is a / or character at the end of the url or a character after / my goal is to redirect to 404.php.

Comment: then put the .htaccess file in the main root directory (main folder) so it will be applicable for all and use the first code that i mentioned

Comment: Hi but I am using 2 different htaccess. I made a mistake at the beginning of the project. d
https://prnt.sc/9Dr1vvdLmf76

Comment: rename the subdirectory .htaccess file to old_htaccess  and use mian directory .htaccess file it will work for your project globally

Comment: I guess I can't. my project is more to mingle. is there any other solution?

Comment: So sorry this is the exact solution I have got for you but I think somewhere you are lacking due to not having to much knowledge of the directory structure that is why you may got confused